# Windows won't boot after re-mounting drive in Linux

Tags: linux

I unmounted a Windows drive in Linux in order to remount it so I would have read/write access to the Windows files. I can no longer boot into Windows but still have access to the files. Is there a way to fix this?

The command I issued to mount the Windows partition read/write-enabled was

```
mount -o rw,mount,rw -t ntfs /dev/sda4 /mnt/ntfs/
```

Comment: What _exactly_ [did you do](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/480433/edit)? Commands please.

Comment: The command `mount -o rw,mount,rw -t ntfs /dev/sda4 /mnt/ntfs` does not remount your partition, and it has two "rw" flags. I think you meant `mount -o remount,rw -t ntfs /dev/sda4 /mnt/ntfs`. What errors are you getting when you try to boot Windows?

Comment: Anyway filesystem type `ntfs` is a pure linux kernel implementation which lacks features (and increases the chances of corrupting something when used read/write). You should be using [`ntfs-3g`](https://manpages.debian.org/ntfs-3g.8.en.html) which is a fuse implementation, that while lacking pure kernel's speed, would have more features. Its manpage also gives a warning about windows' hibernation

Answer (score 0):

Try to use windows cd/usb key and run "Repair my system".

Generally, if You want to use dual boot, and read windows partition, you should disable so called "Fast boot" feature in Windows. It is nicely explained here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/452071/why-disable-fast-boot-on-windows-8-when-having-dual-booting